# How to access run levels in OS X mavericks 10.9?

Tags: linux, path, osx-mavericks, macbook-air

Is there any way to access run level 0 on a Mac just like we do in Linux? 
I ask because I think I blew away my path variable and none of commands working in my terminal, like `ls`, and someone suggested me try to run your Mac in level 0 like we used to do in Linux. 
So is there any way that I can bring my PC in into run level 0?

Because I'm having errors like
none of these commands are running

```
Abhisheks-MacBook-Air:~ abhisheksadana$ ls
-bash: ls: command not found 

Abhisheks-MacBook-Air:~ abhisheksadana$ mkdir
-bash: mkdir: command not found

Abhisheks-MacBook-Air:~ abhisheksadana$ rm-rf
-bash: rm-rf: command not found

Abhisheks-MacBook-Air:~ abhisheksadana$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set path via `export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'` to get the basics working. However if you must, you can boot to single user mode during a reboot.

After which you can edit your bash_profile or bashrc to restore your full path or remove the problematic lines.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492 for booting in single user mode.

Comment: It's a little more typing, but I'd recommend `export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'`. That's the OS default PATH setup. Seems better than just enabling `/bin` and still having lots of common commands that don't work.

Comment: yeah i agree with Spiff, i wasnt saying that PATH='/bin' was the final solution, i meant to have an operating shell so that you could fix what ever you did to break PATH. Its obviously an erroneous line in a config. `vi` is at /usr/bin/vi so at a minimum you probably want to add `/usr/bin` also so that you have a working editor.

Comment: export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' works for me now all of my previous commands(ls ,vi ) are running  :))

Answer (score 0):

Runlevel 0 is halt (shutdown) isn't it?

If you're just trying to fix the problem by rebooting, hold down the power button for 10 seconds to force a shutdown, then release it and press it again to boot.

From the command line, there are commands like `shutdown -h now` or `reboot`, but if you broke your `PATH`, `bash` won't be able to find those commands either.

But in your case, it looks like you just screwed up your `PATH` environment variable, so you should try @j_mcnally's suggesting of fixing your `PATH` before doing something drastic like halting/rebooting the whole system.